# Generic Literal Type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

Following generic function takes an array of type `T` and returns it:

```
const makeGenericArray = <T>(arr: Array<T>) => arr;
const colors = makeGenericArray(['red', 'green', 'blue']); //type string[]
```

Extending `T` with a constraint `string` results in a literal type array:

```
const makeStringArray = <T extends string>(arr: Array<T>) => arr;
const colorsLiteral = makeStringArray(['red', 'green', 'blue']); // type ("red" | "green" | "blue")[]
```

Why does extending the generic type results in this behaviour? I expected `makeStringArray` to accept only string values in the passed array and besides this behave exactly like `makeGenericArray`.

I can't find a explanation in the docs. Can someone explain it to me or point me to the relating parts of the docs?

Comment: I suppose it uses the most strict type it can infer.